Fullcalendar TypeError: arg.resource is undefined
I am using fullcalendar in resourceTimelineXXX mode like this example: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/resourceAreaColumns-grouping-demo
Sometimes when I change thee date range, I get this error:

Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: arg.resource is undefined

when I try to use cellContent like the example here: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/resourceAreaColumns
If I remove cellContent it all works perfectly, but I want to display a different value instead of IDs.
Using console.log(arg) I see that sometimes arg does not have a  resource object but has groupValue object! I see docs and it seems groupValue is used by resourceGroupLabelContent and not from cellContent like I see here: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/resource-group-render-hooks
I don't know why. Any suggestions?
This version doesn't work (cellContent used): https://codepen.io/itajackass/pen/OJeLWVw?editors=001
This version, (removing cellContent) works: https://codepen.io/itajackass/pen/PorYWPa?editors=001
The same json resources/events are used in each case.
I've only set an events on July 2024... please check the console:

Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: arg.resource is undefined

